# AdvancedDataGrid sort number color

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

next to the header of an advancedDataGrid you see a number. This number stays grey no matter what i do. I Already searched 1 hour to find the solution. Very anoying because it should be so simple to change this.

I hope someone could help me with this problem

Answer (score 0):

> Try by changing the
>
> headerRenderer="AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer"
>
> link
>   http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/advancedDataGridClasses/AdvancedDataGridColumn.html

Comment: thank you that would be the most easy way I guess. I decided to change it to a dataGrid because I don't need all the extra functions and they say (some blogs on internet) that the AdvancedDataGrid is a little bit buggy

Comment: It is a good component if you have alot of data and if you want you can disable those controls

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is the 'proposedColor' style of the mx:AdvancedDataGridHeaderRenderer. That'll deal w/the grey.

Now if you wanted to change the default text colour, I had to search high and low figuring that one out. Eventually, I came to realize that if I made an AdvancedDataGridSortItemRenderer and in it put:

```
override protected function commitProperties():void {
    super.commitProperties();
    label.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
}
```

that sets the text colour permanently, which means it would kill your proposedColor.